# Map Testng.xml to a class via @DataProvider?

Tags: java, testng

Currently I have a number of TestNG test cases with the following format

Testng.xml

```
<DataTables xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="..." >
    <Table name="TestCase1">
     <Header>
                    <Column name="Para1" type="String"></Column>
                    <Column name="Para2" type="String"></Column>
                    <Column name="Para3" type="String"></Column>
     </Header>
     <Row>
                    <Value>Value1</Value>
                    <Value>Value2</Value>
                    <Value>Value3</Value>
     </Row>
    </Table>
    <Table name="TestCase2">
    .
    .
    .
```

With the following testcase structure

```
@Listeners (AutomationTestListener.class)
public class TestCase1 extends SeleniumTestBase {

@DataProvider(name = "TestCase1")
public Object[][] dataTable_TestCase1() {       
     return this.getDataTable("TestCase1");
}

@Test (dataProvider = "TestCase1")
public final void tc_TestCase1(final String Data_Para1, String Data_Para2,   
String Data_Para3) {
.
.
.
```

My questions is that is there any way to map the parameters listed in Testng.xml to a class specific for that testcase alone by the `@dataprovider` level? 
The idea I had was to map the `Object[][]` to a class

*edit*

is it possible to map to class like this?

```
Class testCase1Class {
 String para1;
 String parp2;
 String para3;

 public testCase1Class(String a, String b, String c){
   para1 = a;
   para2 = b;
   para3 = c;
  }
 }
```

Then pass a `testCase1Class` object into `@Test`

```
public final void tc_TestCase1(testCase1Class c1)
```

*Note*

1. The method `getDataTable()` will return an array of values
2. The format in testng.xml can not change

Comment: Are you looking for `@Parameters` annotation?

Comment: @talex No, I am trying to pass a class object into the `@test` rather than passing 20-30 parameters into the `tc_TestCase1` function.